# Powershell Script to return binary type of an executable?

Tags: winapi, powershell, wmi

Has anybody ever used Powershell to access the getbinarytype function in the win32 api? I am having some difficulty with it.

Does WMI Win32_Product otherwise contain any information as to the binarytype of an installed software, Office 2010 Professional Plus for instance?

Comment: Have you see here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/getbinarytype.html Tested and works on XP

Comment: I have tried Christian's suggestion above. I attempt "GetBinaryType.ps1 C:\Windows\Explorer.exe" and it returns nothing.

I have attempted to pick apart the script supplied there and isolate the mechanism related to invoking the win32::getbinarytype function with no success. I don't know enough about VBS to implement it that way.

Comment: "GetBinaryType.ps1 C:\Windows\Explorer.exe" on my box (XP pro x86) return BIT32. It works. Your O.s. is?

Comment: nevermind, I was being dumb. The script only supplies a function. I was able to source the GetBinaryType.ps1 and use the Get-BinaryType function to find out the bitness of WINWORD.EXE. Which is my objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, if you have the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) module, you can use the Get-PEHeader command to get this info e.g.:

```
PS> Get-PEHeader 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE'


Type                    : PE32
LinkerVersion           : 9.0
OperatingSystemVersion  : 5.1
ImageVersion            : 10.0
SubsystemVersion        : 5.1
SizeOfCode              : 8192
SizeOfInitializedData   : 1408000
SizeOfUninitializedData : 0
AddressOfEntryPoint     : 4348
BaseOfCode              : 4096
BaseOfData              : 16384
ImageBase               : 805306368
SectionAlignment        : 4096
FileAlignment           : 512
Win32VersionValue       : 0
SizeOfImage             : 1429504
SizeOfHeaders           : 1024
Checksum                : 1424765
Subsystem               : Windows
DllCharacteristics      : 32832
SizeOfStackReserve      : 1048576
SizeOfStackCommit       : 4096
SizeOfHeapReserve       : 1048576
SizeOfHeapCommit        : 4096
LoaderFlags             : 0
```